# Correct way to handle ERROR in TSQL transaction

Tags: c#, sql, .net, t-sql, ado.net

I have transaction in with this structure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XXX @param bit
AS
BEGIN TRAN

IF (@param = 1) BEGIN

   -- DO SOME STUFF LIKE INSERT, UPDATE AND SO ON...
   RETURN 1 -- RETURN 1 FOR SUCCESS
END
ELSE BEGIN
   -- CONDITION IS NOT SUCCESSFUL SO NOTHING HAPPENED AND I NEED HANDLE
   -- IN C#
   RETURN -1
END


BEGIN TRY
   COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRAN
  RETURN -1
END CATCH
```

I've added some return clausule but I don't know if is it good solution, and handle it in c# code? In c# I need handle only 2 states:

- If condition suits, and code done without errors return 1 or true
- Other cases return -1 or false

Is that procedure body ok for that?

Thanks for answers

**EDIT**
For better understand what I need, I've created state diagram:
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the `RaiseError` statement in TSql?  Calling that with the right parameters will cause an exception to be thrown in your C# code.

Comment: Executing COMMIT TRAN will not raise errors generated after the BEGIN TRANS if thats the idea - they are raised when they occur so its odd to TRY/CATCH a COMMIT

Comment: If you RETURN after a BEGIN TRAN you leave it both uncommitted & unrolledback - See http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html for general patterns.

Comment: check updated question please, I've added diagram for required procedure

Comment: I need also handle, if nothing happened in transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me is better to know where was problem during the procedure. RAISEERROR should be best solution. But ofc it can be considered as point of view.

That kind of solution can help me also handle Exception in .NET application.

In this case procedure should seems like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XXX @param bit
AS
BEGIN


DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) 
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT 
DECLARE @ErrorState INT 


BEGIN TRY

BEGIN TRAN TR1   


IF (@param = 1) 
BEGIN

   -- DO SOME STUFF LIKE INSERT, UPDATE AND SO ON...
   -- RETURN 1 FOR SUCCESS
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
   -- CONDITION IS NOT SUCCESSFUL SO NOTHING HAPPENED AND I NEED HANDLE
   -- IN C#
   RAISERROR ('Incorrect input param error.', -- Message text.  
           16, -- Severity.  
           1 -- State.  
           ); 
END

    RETURN 1

COMMIT TRAN TR1
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN TR1

    SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()  
    SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()  
    SET @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE() 


    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,-- Message text.  
               @ErrorSeverity,-- Severity.  
               @ErrorState-- State.  
               );  
-- this catch also possible errors if @param = 1

END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer ... but can you give me example how catch this error in c#? I use ado.net and nothing exception in c# code